# ggplot2で図が表示されたりされなかったりする。

Tags: r, tidyverse, ggplot2

Rでtidyverseとqiime2Rを用いて作図を試みています。
データを入力してスクリプトを実行すると、
1回目は作図されるのですが、図を保存して図ウィンドウ（Quartz）を閉じ、再度同じスクリプトを入力すると、

> UseMethod("depth") でエラー:
> 'depth' をクラス "NULL" のオブジェクトに適用できるようなメソッドがありません

と表示されて作図されません。

同じデータと同じスクリプトを使用しているにもかかわらず、一体何が問題なのでしょうか。
ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。

```
metadata<-read_q2metadata("metadata.tsv")
pco<-read_qza("unweighted_unifrac_pcoa_results.qza")

pco$data$Vectors %>%
  select(SampleID, PC1, PC2) %>%
  left_join(metadata) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=`Strain`, shape=`FeedSex`)) +
  geom_point(alpha=.7, size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(paste("PC1: ", round(100*pco$data$ProportionExplained[1], 2), "%")) +
  ylab(paste("PC2: ", round(100*pco$data$ProportionExplained[2], 2), "%")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,1,17,2,15,0), name="Feed-Sex") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","darkgreen"), name="Strain") +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(order=2), color=guide_legend(order=1)) +
  ggtitle("Unweighted UniFrac") +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1, plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"))
```

R for Mac: 4.0.2
tidyverse: 1.3.0
qiime2R: 0.99.20

reference: Plotting PCoA
https://forum.qiime2.org/t/tutorial-integrating-qiime2-and-r-for-data-visualization-and-analysis-using-qiime2r/4121

書けるだけの情報を記載いたしました。
情報が足りないようでしたらお知らせください。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 出ているエラーメッセージはこれで全てでしょうか？　省略している部分はありますか？

Comment: 回答いただけているにもかかわらず、確認が遅くなり申し訳ございません。都度、違うエラーメッセージが出ていた記憶ですが、最も多かったエラーメッセージが上記でした。省略はしておりません。

Answer (score 1):

過去の事例を探ると、Mac におけるこのエラーは ggplot2 のバグである可能性があります。[コメント](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3538#issuecomment-633306033)によるとグリッド周りのバグのようで、2020 年 7 月現在まだ直っていないように見えます。

- no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL" https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2514
- traceback() for no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL" https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3538

ひとつ目の投稿によると、とりあえずの処置として、`ggplot(ほにゃらら)` でグラフ描画するのではなく、

```r
the_plot <- ggplot(ほにゃらら)
the_plot
```

のようにグラフ描画すると回避できる場合があるようです。

Comment: GitHubのコミュニティまでご確認いただき、ありがとうございました。バグということ、承知いたしました。諦める（納得する）しかないのかもしれませんね。回避策としてご提示いただいた代替スクリプト（？）も、どこまで指定すればよいのかわからないので、都度起動させる方向で、バグが修正されることを気長に待つことにいたします。